# Testing the C++ Containers - Results for insert and push_back

Tags: c++

These 4 containers, vector, list, map, unordered_map...are important b.c. they represent some of the most commonly used data structures.  Internally they are represented as a dynamic array, double linked list, a searchable tree, and a hash.

```
   #include "c_arclib.cpp"
    using namespace std;
    int main()
      {
    /*
    Define - Vector, List, Map, Unordered_map
    */
      vector<int> vector_int;
      list<int> list_int;
      map<int,int> map_int;
      unordered_map<int, int> unordered_map_int; 
    /*
    Define Loop and Time 
    */
      int i,j,loop1=5, loop2=4294967;
      clock_t time_start,time_end,time_diff;
    /*
    Run Timing Test
    */
      for(j=0;j<loop1;j++)
        {
        time_start=clock();
        for(i=0;i<loop2;++i)
          {
          unordered_map_int.insert(pair<int,int>(rand(),rand()));
          /*
          map_int.insert(pair<int,int>(rand(),rand()));
          vector_int.push_back(rand());
          list_int.push_back(rand());
          */
          }
        time_end=clock();
        time_diff=time_end-time_start;
        cout << time_diff << endl;
        }
    /*
    Results
    Push / Insert
    map (insert)                    9500
    unorderd_map (insert)           3300
    list (push)                     2600
    vector (push)                   900
    */
```

Comment: And the purpose of that is...?

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the questions and don't remove the question from the question in the process (Sounds tautological, right?) Also: What you have here is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're probably looking to just do this?

```
cout << (double)(time_end - time_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

Also, there are more accurate timers than `clock()`.

Comment: I know but the resolution is enough to determine the performance of each container with respect to each other.  I'll test your code and add it in.

Answer (score 0):

> The value returned is the CPU time used so far as a clock_t; to get the number of seconds used, divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock

For an easy-to-use C++ interface to `clock()`, consider [`boost::timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/timer/timer.htm).